# Foreach activity does not loop an array of numbers Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure function to retrieve an array, it works very well but the problem I can't pass that array into a foreach activity, it does not iterate the array.
[image]

the result of the function activity :
[image]

the set variable :
[image]

```
@uriComponentToString(replace(uriComponent(activity('Azure Function1').output.Response), '%0D%0A', ''))
```

the result of set variable :
[image]

foreach activity :
[image]

when I execute the pipeline the append activity executes just one time :
[image]

Now the problem is the foreach activity, it treats the array as one value and it pass it to the append vaiable inside the foreach, how can resolve this proble please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [GregGalloway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5070440/greggalloway). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> Use `@json(variables('result'))` instead of `@array(variables('result'))` in item field of ForEach activity

[image]

Answer (score 1):

result variable is already an array. I think you need not convert to array like this while passing on to the foreach loop.'

```
@array(variables('result'))
```

Instead, just pass on the variable value directly like

```
@variables('result')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have already pass @variables('result'), but I got the same result

Comment: @Javauser please try @json(variables('result'))

Comment: @javauser, result is array variable? Or string

Comment: @allaboutbi, it is string

Comment: ok, makes sense.